# Conditionally link to symbol at load time

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I want to have a single build of a Win32 program for Windows 7 or 8. I want to be able to support touch injection on Windows 8. `InitializeTouchInjection` is the symbol to initialize this, but only available in Windows 8. Is there a way at load time, or run time to check the Windows version and the link to this symbol? Currently I get undefined linkage when loading in Windows 7.

Comment: You might want to read about the [dynamic link library functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682599%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in the Windows API.

Comment: Use delayload or GetProcAddress

Comment: Using GetProcAddress solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using GetProcAddress allows the code to check if the symbol exits, if not then alternate behavior is provided. In this case touch injection is only in windows 8.

```
typedef BOOL(WINAPI *InitTouch) (_In_ UINT32 maxCount, _In_ DWORD dwMode);

InitTouch fp =  (InitTouch)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("User32.dll")),                               
                                  "InitializeTouchInjection");
if ((fp != NULL) && fp(TOUCH_LIMIT, TOUCH_FEEDBACK_DEFAULT))
{
    // Behavio(u)r with the feature
}
else
{
    // Behavio(u)r without the feature
}
```